# Last LinearLayout of a RelativeLayout inside a scroll view is not displayed

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

First of all, I roamed the web for an answer, but wasn't able to fix my problem.

I have the following scroll view inside a layout:

```xml
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_cover_picture"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"/>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/list_flags"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/img_cover_picture"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_cover_picture"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#F5F5F5"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/list_infos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_title"
            android:textColor="#BABBBB"
             />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/view_blog_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_infos"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
             />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_blog_count"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#F5F5F5"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/list_categories"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_description"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
             />



    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**The empty LinearLayouts are filled programatically.**

What I expect is that when the content displayed in the RelativeLayout is too big, the ScrollView allows the user to scroll to see all the content.

Problem is: when it happens, he can scroll, but the last LinearLayout (identified by list_categories) is *never displayed*.
I have tried all sort of things:

- Maybe as it is filled programatically it was empty? I tried to put it below @id/view_blog_count to check, and it was displayed (overlaying the description)
- I tried to use set fillViewport to true
- I tried to change the weights
- I tried to play with the layout(_width|_height)
- ...

No success so far :(

Thanks for your help!

Gaaston

---

**UPDATE**

I know the LinearLayouts are empty, but they are filled programatically (and I'm sure they are). And besides, I tried to add a TextView in the empty LinearLayout as a test but the LinearLayout was still hidden.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I'm using a RelativeLayout so that the flags (list_flags) are over the cover picture (img_cover_picture). However as @lelloman suggested I did try with a horizontal LinearLayoout instead. It still did not work :)

Comment: Does it be displayed if you put a TextView with a text in your XML ?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it is still hidden :(

Comment: do you really need a relativelayout there? why don't you try with a linearlayout instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @lelloman, I originally used a LinearLayout so that the "list_flags" view would be over the "img_cover_picture" view. However I will give it a try. EDIT: well it did not work, but thank you anyway :)

Comment: I think that if you're sure those linearlayouts are not empty, maybe they're overlapped by other views...personally I hate relativelayout ^^

Comment: Well it did not work with a linear layout, so I guess that's not an overlapping problem :( but thank you

Comment: mmm did you removed the layout_below attributes to your views when trying with a linearlayout containter? layout_below belongs to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: I'm starting to believe that this is a ScrollView issue, as I have a similar type of problem at the moment. I'll be monitoring this question.

Comment: lelloman yes I tried this :( @Sandervan'tVeer arg okay, that's why I wasn't able to solve this .. Have you got any leads yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I have a ScrollView containing a LinearLayout which gets views added to it dynamically. These views don't always show as the ScrollView does not seem to resize properly. I have to reload the ScrollView twice for it to resize like it should. I've tried invalidating the layout (.invalidate()), requesting it again (.requestLayout()) and several variaties on this but still, no cigar.

Comment: @Gaaston do you try to put your LL at the top of the XML and / or to just put it alone in the RL ? Let's determine if it's a general problem or just this LL

Comment: @PlumillonForge I'm not sure I got your question, the LL is never alone in its RL, there are other elements (TextViews, LLs) that are displayed.

Comment: That's the idea, can you try to remove all your other View beside this LL ? Just to see if this is this particular LL which is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a tweak that did the trick:

At the end of the RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView, I added the following element.

```xml
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_categories"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="TEST"/>
```

And.. it worked, the last linear layout is now there. Looks like it's really the *last* view that is not displayed.

Now I know that it is tweak, so I won't validate this yet, in case someone comes up with a cleaner idea. But if anyone is stuck with that, this is the best I found!

Thanks anyway for the help guys :)

Cheers

Gaaston